# ExtJS progress bar in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to add a progress bar in the footer (fbar) of a Grid? I have been successful in adding buttons to the grid panel but no luck with the progress bar.

I tried this in the fbar:

```
fbar: [{
                type: 'progress',
                text: 'updating...'
      }]
```

But the result is a button with the text "updating" being added to the footer.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Ext4

```
Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*']);

Ext.define('Restaurant', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'cuisine']
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var restaurants = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'restaraunts',
        model: 'Restaurant',
        data: [{
            name: 'Cheesecake Factory',
            cuisine: 'American'
        }]
    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: restaurants,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        frame: true,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Cuisine',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'cuisine'
        }],
        fbar: [{
            xtype: 'progressbar',
            text: 'Foo',
            width: 200
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you let me know how would you access the object of this progress bar? I mean what would be the way if i want to update the progress ?

Comment: Use var progress = grid.down('progressbar');